# CSS Styling of Dropdown menu with drop shadows/etc

Tags: css, shadow

Just received some great help on here and thought I'd ask for a little more. Novice to CSS and I would like to style a drop-down menu with a nice drop shadow (not sure if this is the correct term) so that it fits in with the rest of the menu (which came as part of a theme).

I am learning CSS and understand how to apply basic shadows, but it is a bit beyond me to style this menu exactly like the existing one in the drop-down.

I include the code of the menu below, but its easier visible by visiting www.acehscmaths.com/welcome/testhome - the menu I am looking to style is the one called charts, which if you click on drops down.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="side-bar-wrapper collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

        <ul class="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="charts.html" class="is-dropdown-menu">
                    <span class="badge pull-right"></span>
                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> Charts
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html#area_chart_anchor">
                            <i class="icon-random"></i>
                            Area Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html#circle_chart_anchor">
                            <i class="icon-bullseye"></i>
                            Circular Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html#bar_chart_anchor">
                            <i class="icon-signal"></i>
                            Bar Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html#line_chart_anchor">
                            <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
                            Line Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="side-bar-wrapper collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

        <ul class="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="newquestion">
                    <i class="icon-question"></i> Question
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="side-bar-wrapper collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

        <ul class="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="newnotes">
                    <i class="icon-book"></i> Study Notes
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks again and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can always click on inspect element on your chrome or firefox to see the css styling and learn something new :)
in this case its:

```
background-color: #2e3340;
margin: 0px -3px;
padding: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

the open menu however is done with query.

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about replicating that styling down to the drop-down however?

Comment: try : .side-bar-wrapper .side-menu > li > ul  its the ul thats inside the li thats inside the ul class .side-menu thats inside .side-bar-wrapper. should work without the arrows as well : .side-bar-wrapper .side-menu  li  ul  OR  .side-bar-wrapper .side-menu ul li  ul

Comment: Hi, sorry, I must be misunderstanding, I already have this CSS in my app.css which I think is the same as above:   .side-bar-wrapper .side-menu > li > ul {
  background-color: #2e3340;
  margin: 0px -3px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    

}

Comment: Yes, thats the css styling from the link you provided. this is not what you were after?

Comment: Ah sorry, I was hoping to apply CSS styling similar to that you see for the single menu items ("Charts", "Questions", "Study Notes") to the drop-down menu under "Charts", if that makes sense. Once you click on charts there are no shadows and I'm struggling to get nice shadows on that menu.

Comment: ok got ya :) do you want it to apper beneath each li element kinda like a seperator? or under the whole block of the sub menu?

Comment: the box-shadow is set to inset which means its on the inside. if you take away the inset it will be on the outside. hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your patience. I'd like it to look like www.acehscmaths.com/welcome/testhome2 but with the dropdown effect (i.e. not moving other divs) of www.acehscmaths.com/testhome - there is only one difference in the CSS between the 2 versions, the version with the dropdown but poorer styling has the following CSS added: 

.side-menu {
    position:relative;
}
.side-menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    width:100%;
}

Comment: there is almost no difference, the shadow is still there, you just cant see it because of the white contrast. try plying with the numbers, for example :  0px 1px 14px 0px

Comment: Hi, just tried that - thanks. Still looks different. For example the shadows look different but the rounded corners disappear also?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the feature you're looking for is the css-property **box-shadow**.
Apply it on the div representing the menu.
Box shadow supports the following arguments in the here noted sturcture:

offset-x, offset-y, blur-x, blur-y, shadow-color

```
#example1 {
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```