# Add shadows in the dropdown menu

Tags: css, wordpress, box-shadow

i am trying to add shadows at here: http://prntscr.com/eiyg7i

- But i cant figure that out.

I've added this code:

```
.nav-dropdown {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

but it just make the box shadow to none.

Edit: i have added this code

```
.nav-dropdown {
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 6px 21px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 6px 21px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 2px 6px 21px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

but it still gets wrong http://94.247.169.169/~welloteket/ - it still get shadows here at the top

Comment: `box-shadow` cannot be limited to sides like margin, padding ord border can. You could probably use a linear gradient on a border-image here.

Comment: Use this site - it's great for these things: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Styling of Dropdown menu with drop shadows/etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829212/css-styling-of-dropdown-menu-with-drop-shadows-etc)

Comment: Hmm, i cant figure that out. It still get wrong...

Comment: You need to make yourself familiar with what the values you assign to `box-shadow` actually man. I've added basic info in my code sample below.

Answer (score 5):

You can offset the `box-shadow` in horizontal and vertical direction. Unfortunately doing so will make the shadow appear more prominent on the side you shift it to.

Would this work for you?

http://codepen.io/connexo/pen/gmWjNJ

```css
.bar {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  height: 60px;
}
.dropdown {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  box-shadow:     0      10px      10px       #666;
  /*              |        |         |
              x-shift      |         |
                        y-shift      |
                               size of shadow
  */
}


/* This uses z-index
.bar2 {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="dropdown"></div>

<div class="bar2"></div>
<div class="dropdown2"></div>
```

Comment: but now it looks a bit funny :P

Comment: Thank you, i think i understand now. But how do i make the shadows more opacity?

Comment: I have added a second example showing how I would solve the problem. I would make sure the bar above the box with the shadow has a higher z-index so it covers the boxe's unwanted top shadow.